# How to create a observable List in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to update my text whenever there is a new element added to my list..
I tried to do this by below code..

```
var myList: MutableList<ArrayList<String>> by Delegates.observable(mutableListOf(), onChange = { _, _, new ->
    Constants.debug("Value Changed")
})
```

But it doesn't seem to work.. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It doesn't work because the observabe delegate only observes changes to the *variable*, not to the object *stored in that variable*. So when the list changes, the variable still points to the same list, and the observable delegate has no idea anything has changed. To observe that, you need some means of actually observing the contents of the list, which is not something Kotlin or Java provides out of the box. You'll need some kind of observable list for that.

Alternatively, you could use a standard list (instead of a mutable one), and whenever you need to change the list, replace it with the new version of the list. This way you can listen to changes just like you want to, but probably need to adjust a lot of other code using that list.

Comment: Ah that makes sense.. Thanks

Comment: A bit late, but you could wrap a Collection implementation in a custom class and override the get/remove methods. This way you can trigger you listeners.

Comment: The idea of using immutable is great. Kotlin makes it easy to create new lists upon list. And by the way, your list is more robust against concurrency issues

Answer (score 10):

You can use something like this :

```
class ObservableList<T>(private val wrapped: MutableList<T>): MutableList<T> by wrapped, Observable() {
    override fun add(element: T): Boolean {
        if (wrapped.add(element)) {
            setChanged()
            notifyObservers()
            return true
        }
        return false
    }
}
```

Comment: Very interesting, thank you :) I was not aware delegate could be used like this.

Comment: If you're referring to `java.util.Observable`, then this is already deprecated.

Answer (score 4):

I am very late on this one but have developed a library that supplies observable collections.

At present it includes the following collections:

**Lists**
ArrayList
LinkedList
Stack
Vector

**Maps**
ArrayMap
ConcurrentHashMap
LinkedHashMap
TreeMap
WeakHashMap

**Queues**
ArrayBlockingQueue
ArrayDeque
DelayDeque
LinkedBlockingQueue
LinkedTransferQueue
PriorityBlockingQueue
Queue
SynchronousQueue

**Sets**
HashSet
LinkedHashSet
TreeSet

More will be added as time permits and per requests.

You can find it at 
https://github.com/theblitz/ObservableCollections

and is available for gradle on jcenter() like this:

> implementation 'il.co.theblitz:observablecollections:1.2.0'